# jquery hide options in select exept one empty value

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to hide (not remove!) all options from a select exept one?
So in the example below i only want to show the option with the empty value and hide the others.

```
<select>
  <option value="">Kies een waarde</option>
  <option value="1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="3">Value 2</option>
</select?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i only want to show the option with the empty value and hide the others.

You can try with attribute selector

```
$("#selectId").find('option[value!=""]').hide();
```

Comment: he wants to hide the options and not remove, and those he wants to hide is not the default one

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam True. Updated.

Comment: that's more like it .

Comment: Thanks! Part one works, next question: How to unhide them after, because when i use $("#rubriek").show(); only one option is shown

Comment: @JilcoTigchelaar Just `$("#selectId").find('option[value!=""]').show();`

Comment: yep, as simple as that! Thanks